# Azure Snapshot Debugger For Centos

Tags: azure, debugging, snapshot, azure-application-insights

I am running a .NET Core application as a server application on a Centos 7 on-premise machine and using Azure App Service for a client application. I have added Application Insights to .NET Core Application and I can inspect things such as operations and exceptions on Azure portal.

What I desire next is to enable Snapshot Debugger for my .NET Core application. However, in the supported environments section on this page; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger, there is no sign of support for any Linux distributions, I, actually, suspected for a chance because of .NET Core support existence but I could not find any question about this issue at all.

So, is Snapshot Debugger supported for .NET Core applications running on Centos? If Snapshot Debugger is not supported for Centos, can you suggest me a way to debug exceptions thrown on Centos on-premise machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer on Snapshot Debugger here.
No, Snapshot Debugger is not currently supported on Linux distros.
Please see my more complete answer here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/188#issuecomment-371233256

Comment: The link in the answer is dead WaybackMachine link : https://web.archive.org/web/20200916210727/https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/188
Active link in the new dedicated repo : https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SnapshotCollector/issues/2